# How to insert Ajax Passed image as Blob In Mysql Using Mysqli(PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I am trying to upload image using ajax on client side and on server side i am using PHP. The Problem i am facing is, i am unable to save the image in Mysql database table as a blob using PHP. I am unable to define Receive function of image.

I need help on how to define receive function and save blob image in database column.
am i missing something in my PHP code below ??

Java Script:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                $("#targetLayer").html(data);
                },
                error: function() 
                {
                }           
           });
        }));
    });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post">

    <div id="uploadFormLayer">
    <label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
    <input name="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" />
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxx","xxx"); 

$image = addslashes(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));

    $query = "INSERT INTO images (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";  

    $qry = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Add 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' in your form

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 $query = "INSERT INTO images (id,image) VALUES('','" . mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents($image)) . "')";
```

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\php_ajax_image_upload\upload.php on line 5`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Detect if POST
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  // Check $_FILES array
  if(isset($_FILES["inputFile"])){

    // Find location of uploaded file
    $tmpName = $_FILES["inputFile"]["tmp_name"];

    // Read data
    $fileHandle = fopen($tmpName, "r");
    $image = fread($fileHandle, filesize($tmpName));
    fclose($fileHandle);

    // Run query
    $db = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxx","xxx"); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";  
    $qry = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  }
}
```

Please remember to add your own security regarding file size and type. Here is the [PHP file upload documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Also, not sure why you pass an empty string into the id column in your table. If this field has auto_increment (such as with the SERIAL data type), then you can just leave that field blank in the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES('$image');
```

Comment: Thank s For the reply

Comment: Error is not showing up now, But image is also not saving..but Was expecting the same answer as u have posted..

Comment: Check the value of `$_FILES["inputFile"]["error"]`. If it is not zero (success), then read the documentation on error codes.

Comment: TK didn't work nothing is saving in db nor any error is showing up :(

Comment: Then you may want to check the documentation for mysqli_connect and mysqli_query to see how to print out errors from those functions.